# Replicating tables from different databases postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have tables from different databases , and i want to create a data warehouse database that contains table replicas from different tables from different databases. I want the data in the warehouse to be synced with the data from the other tables everyday.I am using postgresql

I tried to do this using psql :

> pg_dump -t table_to_copy source_db | psql target_db

However it didnt work as it keeps stating errors like table does no exist.
It all worked when i dumped the whole dabatase not only a single table, but however i want the data to be synced  and i want to copy tables from different databases not the whole database.

How can i do this?
Thanks!

Comment: `... it keeps stating errors like table does no exist.` What was the error message you got?

Comment: @joopERROR:  type "u_datetime" does not exist
LINE 3:     ts_created u_datetime DEFAULT now(),
                       ^
ERROR:  relation "customer" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "customer" does not exist

Comment: is `u_datetime` a UDT ? If it is, it must exist in the target database too -->> you'll need to create it before you create the table that depends on it.

Comment: @joop i dont want to use pg-dump since it doesnt allow data syncing between tables.Any other method?

Comment: @joop create domain u_datetime    timestamptz;

Comment: Well add that (domain) definition before creating and importing the table + data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134972/discussion-between-abdalla-ismail-and-joop).

Comment: You could use foreign data wrappers to access tables from multiple Postgres servers

Comment: how can i sync the data regularly

Comment: @Abdalla Ismail can you check my edit of dblink.. Install and it might help

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need FDW - Foreign Data Wrapper. You can create foreign tables for different external db in different schemas on local db. All tables accessible by local queries. For storing snap you can use local tables with just `INSERT INTO local_table_YYYY_MM SELECT * FROM remote_table;` .

Answer (score 0):

**1**

```
 pg_dump -t <table name> <source DB> | psql -d <target DB>
```

(Check the table name correctly and it says for you , table doesn't exist)

**2**

[pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html) allows the dumping of only select tables:

```
pg_dump -Fc -f output.dump -t tablename databasename
```

*(dump 'tablename' from database 'databasename' into file 'output.dump' in pg_dumps binary custom format)*

You can restore that [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgrestore.html):

```
pg_restore -d databasename output.dump
```

If the table itself already exists in your target database, you can import only the rows by adding the `--data-only` flag.

**Dblink**

You can not perform cross database query like SQL Server, PostgreSQL does not support this. DbLink extension of PostgreSQL which is used to connect one database to another database. You have to install and configure DbLink to execute cross database query.

Here is the step by step script and example for executing cross database query in PostgreSQL. Please visit this [**post**:](http://www.dbrnd.com/2015/05/postgresql-cross-database-queries-using/)

Comment: Postgres does not allow cross-database queries.

Comment: @joop I didn't know that thanx. How about modified solution which also works for transfer from one server to another

Comment: Well, that is basically the same as the method in the question. (he uses plain (text) format piped into psql, you use custom format + pg_restore)

Comment: @joop i guess there is something wrong with table name ! Error itself says